# Jquery toggle with position absolute bottom

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle, css-position

I've got an `absolute` positioned container, which is `bottom` aligned.

Now I would like to `toggle` (show/hide) some content without the container getting larger than its contents -  and preferably without setting the height explicitly.

### html

```
<div id="outer">
    <div class="expandableContent">
        <p class="toggler">Toggle</p>
        <div>
            <p>Some content here</p>
            <p>Some content there</p>
            <p>Some content everywhere</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
#outer {
     height: 300px;
     position: relative;
}

.expandableContent {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}

 .expandableContent > div {
     display: none;
 }
```

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toggler').click( function() {
        $(this).next().toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Here's a link: http://jsfiddle.net/SunnyRed/A8pNv/1/

Comment: From now on paste your code here as well as the jsfiddle. Currently your problem has been rectified but others who will come across this problem can not find it easily on stackoverflow. Thank you

Comment: Sry, added it. Css is lightly stripped, but contains all necessary definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set the height...just the width of the explandable div. I have modified this for you in your jsfiddle.

The only thing i did was:

```
 .expandableContent {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Omg! That's nasty :) Big Thanks. Sidenote: Either your changes to my the fiddle aren't saved or I do not know how to access the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

```
width: 100%;
white-space:nowrap;
```

Add the above the the div containing the text.

xGreen is correct that setting the width will work, but some browsers with also require text-wrapping to be disabled. An example would be with Chrome, just setting the width is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, is much elegant now.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8pNv/4/)**